# How to go to previous page in category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a knowledge base, and i want to import the fuction to be able to go to the previous page on my taxonomy page's.

I already tried `javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)`. and it worked good, but the problem is, if someone goes directly to the link, and clicks on previous page, it will go back to the last page they have visited.

```
<a href="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)" class="pl-3">Previous page</a>


$post_object = get_field('support_related');
    $class = 'col-12';

  if ($post_object) {
    $class = 'col-9';
  }
  ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $class;?> block">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body searchbody p-4">
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div> <!-- . / card-body -->
      </div> <!-- card -->
    </div> <!-- . / block -->
  <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to be able to go to the previous page inside the taxonomy's.

Comment: what do you mean by previous category ?

Comment: you mean the previous article in the same category ?

Comment: You need to define the logic for what "previous page" actually is, what it actually *means*. For example; the logic for a "previous day of the week" would be the current day in the "**set**" (Monday-->Sunday)  minus 1 (`-1`) . Please **EDIT** your question and clearly explain your logic - is previous alphabetically, by ID number, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Doc:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

```
<?php previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ); ?>
```

> **in_same_term (boolean) (optional):**
>
> Indicates whether previous post must
>   be within the same taxonomy term as the current post. If set to
>   'true', only posts from the current taxonomy term will be displayed.
>   If the post is in both the parent and subcategory, or more than one
>   term, the previous post link will lead to the previous post in any of
>   those terms.
>
> - true
> - false
>
> *Default: false*

Make it true , to get in the previous post in the same taxonomy .

And the defaut value of taxonomy is *cateogry* .

The same thing for next post .